# I got this error when I compile pdf in r weave

Tags: r, pdf, compilation, tex

Please I need help . I got this error when I try to compile pdf in r sweave

[image]

Comment: You need to install latex. Personally I recommend texlive, but many r users seem to use tinytex

Comment: I download tinytex but still does not work, could you recommend something else

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
install.package("tinytex")
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```